# Spark on EMR | EKS |YARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, amazon-eks

I am getting migrated from on-premise to the AWS stack. I have a doubt and often confused about how Apache spark works in AWS/similar.

1. I will just share my current understanding about the onpremise spark that run on yarn.  When the application is submitted  in the spark cluster,an application master will be created in any of the data node (as containers) and this will take care of the application by **spawning executor tasks in the data nodes.** This means the spark code will be deployed to the node where the data resides. This means less network transfer. More over this is  logical and easy to visualise (at least to me.)

   But, suppose there is a same spark application that runs on AWS. This fetches the data from S3 and run on top of  eks. Here as I understand the spark drvier and the **executor tasks  will be spawn on a k8s pod**.

-Then does this mean, data has to be transferred through network from S3 to EKS cluster to the node where the executor pod gets spawned ?

2. I have seen some of the videos that uses EMR on top of EKS. But I am a little confused here.

-Since EMR provides spark runtime, why do we use EKS here? Can't we run EMR alone for spark applications in actual production environment? (I know that EKS, can be a replacement to YARN in spark world)

-Can't we run spark on top of EKS without using EMR? (I am thinking emr as a cluster where in spark drivers and executors can run )

Edit - This is a query more on k8s with spark integration. Not specific to AWS.